# Problems with implementing sorting of list of objects

Tags: java

I have list of objects that looks like this

```
List<Color> colorList = generateColorList(10);

System.out.println(colorList);

System.out.println(colorList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())); //Sorting

// [Color{colors=[#91E7CE, #FCEF32, #859BDF], isPrimary=true, rgb={r=126, b=155, g=112}}, 
// Color{colors=[#E53DE3, #589003, #12AC95], isPrimary=false, rgb={r=111, b=140, g=232}}, 
// Color{colors=[#90381C, #83E0A5, #D88C51], isPrimary=false, rgb={r=234, b=154, g=3}}, 
// Color{colors=[#D40BF0, #8625B4, #CA1F2A], isPrimary=false, rgb={r=198, b=231, g=18}}, 
// Color{colors=[#FB1203, #970BFA, #7FEA33], isPrimary=false, rgb={r=238, b=7, g=56}}, 
// Color{colors=[#68FB95, #34DBE8, #8953EF], isPrimary=true, rgb={r=121, b=171, g=167}}, 
// Color{colors=[#9D85F3, #1455AE, #374475], isPrimary=false, rgb={r=225, b=177, g=70}}, 
// Color{colors=[#43466A, #F3CD61, #3962FB], isPrimary=false, rgb={r=12, b=163, g=194}}, 
// Color{colors=[#311731, #8BF4FD, #40EF0C], isPrimary=true, rgb={r=89, b=80, g=153}}, 
// Color{colors=[#9015A9, #603793, #62F78B], isPrimary=true, rgb={r=111, b=253, g=88}}]
```

It has three datatypes that are listed in my class below

I want to sort them by isPrimary field

Color.class

```
public class Color implements Serializable, Comparable {
    private List<String> colors;
    @JsonProperty("isPrimary")
    private boolean primary;
    private HashMap<String,Integer> rgb = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    public Color(){};

public List<String> getColors() {
    return colors;
}

public void setColors(List<String> colors) {
    this.colors = colors;
}

public boolean GetIsPrimary() {
    return primary;
}

public void setIsPrimary(boolean primary) {
    this.primary = primary;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> getRgb() {
    return rgb;
}

public void setRgb(HashMap<String, Integer> rgb) {
    this.rgb = rgb;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Color{" +
            "colors=" + colors +
            ", isPrimary=" + primary +
            ", rgb=" + rgb +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Color o1 = (Color)this;
    Color o2 = (Color)o;
    return o1.GetIsPrimary().compareTo(o2.GetIsPrimary());
}
```

}

I was trying to repeat after my tutor but he had String and i have boolean and it tells me that method compareTo is not resolved(the last method in Color class)
How can i make it working?

Comment: You can't call `compareTo` on a primitive. Look at the javadoc for `compareTo` and implement it yourself.

Comment: Helps pls God will bless you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

- `Comparable` is a generic interface so it should be `implements Comparable<Color>`
- Then change your `compareTo` method to

```
public int compareTo(Color o) {
    return this.GetIsPrimary().compareTo(o.GetIsPrimary());
}
```

- Change your `getters` and `setters` and `primary field` to use `Boolean` rather than `boolean`.  Then you will be able to use `compareTo` as it is now an object.

Note:

- methods, by convention, should start with lower case letters.
- if a method returns a `boolean`, it is usually preceded with `is`.  Like `isPrimary()`.

Also note that you don't need to implement the Comparable interface to sort.  Assuming the `colorList` is mutable, you can do it as follows by using a Comparator in the sort method.

```
colorList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Color::GetIsPrimary));
```